# Use find() in textarea val with HTML characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

I have a textarea that I want to get the value of and then count the number of opening and closing divs. I am having trouble with the rendered HMTL, even though it's all been escaped I still get errors like this: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: &lt;div&gt;This is a test&lt;/div&gt;` when entering `<div>This is a test</div>` into the textarea.

I would love to be able to keep the HTML tags in the content ie the ability to search for `<div` as apposed to `&lt;div`

**HTML**

```
<h3>Paste your code in here</h3>
<textarea name="code" id="code" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<p>
    <a href="#" class="test-code-btn">Go for it!</a>
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('.test-code-btn').on('click', function(){
    function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
        return unsafe
             .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
             .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
             .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
             .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
             .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }

    var res = escapeHtml($('#code').val());
    console.log('res = ' + res);

    var openDivs = $(res).find('&lt;div').length;
    var closeDivs = $(res).find('&lt;/div').length;

    console.log('openDivs: ' + openDivs + ', closeDivs: ' + closeDivs);
});
```

Comment: The `.find()` method doesn't do a text-based search, it looks for descendant DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a pre built jquery function that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that could start you right!

It works in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MpLqVR?editors=1011).

```
var openCounter=0;
var closeCounter=0;

var raw = $('#code').val();
for(i=0;i<raw.length;i++){
  if( raw.charAt(i)=="<" ){
    if( raw.charAt(i+1)=="\/" ){
      //console.log("One close tag");
      closeCounter++;
    }else{
      //console.log("One open tag");
      openCounter++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(openCounter+" opening tags and "+closeCounter+" closing tags.");
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)